# XNA ClickOnce: Cannot Start Application. What to change?

Tags: xna, installation, clickonce, manifest, windows-7-x64

I have made an XNA game about the 2012 elections a while back ( see here http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/games/votebuster.html ), and to get it to play online, I've used JSIL. However, I've noticed JSIL is still a bit complicated for some computers and it won't run well in them, so I've been looking into different options, then learned about ClickOnce. I've published my game through ClickOnce as CD/DVD files and while the publishing is error-free, I couldn't get it to run (see the question that got me tumbleweed [Clickonce application won't run after installation in XNA 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393005/clickonce-application-wont-run-after-installation-in-xna-4-0) ). Now I believe I know what the error is since my game uses 4 txt files and apparently these are not included with the contents in the publication. So to prove my theory I'm using a try catch as instructed here: [I can not run a published application on another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446279/i-can-not-run-a-published-application-on-another-computer) , for which I add to add System.Windows.Forms as reference. I'm guessing the "FilenotFoundException" should appear upon running, but while I've installed an uninstalled my app countless times before and never got it to run, this time I can't install it for some reason. I get this error once the installation seems to finish:

`Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.` (which I guess means me)

Along with this message, there are two buttons: Ok, and `Details`. When I press details, a notepad file pops up, with the following:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.1008
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.1008 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///E:/My%20Projects/XNA/Finished/VoteBuster/VoteBuster/VoteBuster/publish/VoteBuster.application
    Application url         : file:///E:/My%20Projects/XNA/Finished/VoteBuster/VoteBuster/VoteBuster/publish/Application%20Files/VoteBuster_1_0_0_0/VoteBuster.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : VoteBuster.application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4915d412ad8da99, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : VoteBuster.exe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4915d412ad8da99, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of E:\My Projects\XNA\Finished\VoteBuster\VoteBuster\VoteBuster\publish\VoteBuster.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall the preexisting application.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:15 PM] : Activation of E:\My Projects\XNA\Finished\VoteBuster\VoteBuster\VoteBuster\publish\VoteBuster.application has started.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:15 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:15 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:15 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=x86 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=x86.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=x86 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=x86.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Avatar, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Avatar, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=x86 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=x86.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842CF8BE1DE50553, processorArchitecture=x86 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=x86.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:18 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:19 PM] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:19 PM] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [8/16/2013 11:04:19 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Subscription)
        - Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall the preexisting application.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckApplicationPayload(CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

From the error, I get that clickonce is `Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall the preexisting application` , yet I checked and at first there was an instance of the game already installed. I uninstalled it, (didn't just delete, I did it through Control Panel) and still, the same error persists. It also says that I could try to `modify the manifest version for this application`, but that's where I'm stuck. I don't have a clue of what to modify `>.<` . The manifest within the `Application Files` folder of the published game is here http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/VoteBusterexemanifest.txt in txt format since putting it up here exceeds the characters allowed for the question. Please anyone, let me know what might be causing this if you can, any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The message clearly says your application is not completely removed from the system.

Check in Registry for your application.
Location is

> HKCU\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.

Copy the Uninstall string from your app and execute in command prompt.

If your application is successfully uninstalled, then you must need to clear the application cache.

Open command prompt and run `rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache`

If this does not succeeds, go to

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Apps

and delete the folder.

Please make sure there are no other clickonce applications installed in your machine, before deleting the folder.

Try with these scenario, and let me know if this answer helps by accepting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open command prompt by inputting cmd in Run from Start menu.
2. Switch to the path which mage.exe is in. In my side, the path is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin. Input "cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin".
3. Now input Mage.exe -cc. It will appears a notice: Application cache cleared.